# Expectation of vector norm, with independent gaussian components

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $z = [Z_0, Z_1, \text{ ... } , Z_d ]^{\top}$ and we can assume that the $\Sigma$ matrix is diagonal, is it possible to reduce this expectation?

$$\mathbb{E}_{z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma))} [||z||]$$

If it's any help, I believe that if one assumes that $\Sigma = I$, then the non-central chi distribution can be used to obtain the following expectation:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} }L^{\frac{d}{2}-1}_{\frac{1}{2}} \bigg( -\frac{ \||\mu||^2}{2} \bigg),$$
where $L$ is the Laguerre function. Check out the wikipedia for the non-central chi, to explain this result (It's essentially by definition). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution

Note: apologies if my notation is poor, or my question isn't clear.. if I could improve this post please let me know, it's my first one after all..

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/144893/119261